# 120V output relay from AC or DC

Tags: relay, solid-state-relay

What's the best method to switch a ≥15A 120V AC relay using both a 24VDC input or current sensing a 120VAC load. In other words, the NC relay will open if either (1) there's a load on a 120VAC line (>100mA), or (2) if 24VDC is applied to the relay, or (3) if both occur at the same time.

Comment: With what tolerances? relays have poor tolerance. to act  as comparators.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the 'simplest' way is using a current sense relay for the load sensor and a simple 24VDC relay for the DC input. Contacts in parallel switching the coil of your power relay (you didn't spec the coil for that).

I said simplest, not cheapest, of course.